# Mixing public / private data within single call

Tags: javascript, api, falcor

I recently read about falcor JS and thought it might be a good alternative to relay + graphQL. Has anyone used it for decently sized project with some complexity tell me how it performs.

Also maybe give me some clues on how to deal with data within sets that need to be authenticated before you can access them. How would the dataset look for a query that includes public / protected data?

Answer (score 1):

We are using Falcor for a large project, it deals with +/- 15 million request daily including authentication related ones.

What we do to structure, what the Falcor team refers too as, the JSON graph is always stick to the `somethingById` -> `UID` -> `data model` structure.

For example:

```
 {
    "productById": {
        "1234": {
            "Name": "Foo",
            "Weight": 500,
            "Price": 50
        }
    }
}
```

Now, to answer your question about the authentication piece, the [Falcor-router](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor-router) is the answer to solve that issue.

For example, let's say that you have a product, which price is based on the authenticated user, if you want to request the price through the falcor router, the request url might look something like this: `/model.json?paths=[["productById",1234,"Price"]]&method=get`

In the router you could do something like this:

```
{
    route: "productById[{integers:productIds}]['Price']",
    get: function(pathSet){
       // do something related to pricing   
    }
}
```

Long story short, Falcor can be used to do authentication related things through the router. I would strongly encourage you to look at the videos posted by [Jafar Husain](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyE9BCWDVdhwwZckhR7MI7w)